# In building chat application, is Web Service better to use than JMS, RMI, or Socket programming?

Tags: java, sockets, jms, rmi, vps

In building java chat application, is Web Service better to use than JMS, RMI, or Socket programming?

My VPS has the ff: 512MB Memory, 1 Core Processor, 20GB SSD Disk and 1TB Transfer.

My target number of users in the same time is, 5-30.

I think the way to handle the changes in chatbox is using Polling. 
Is my VPS can handle that load if I am using web service?

If I am going to use other technologies like RMI or JMS? 
Is my VPS can handle it?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a web frontend for your chat, using websockets (if you want to use java on the backend, it's supported by jetty but also by other http servers) instead of polling is a more common approach.

Definitely no JMS,RMI or sockets, if the client is a browser, if it's a desktop client using something based on sockets and a custom protocol could be the easiest way to go.

The number of connections your VPS will handle is dependant on many factors, included how performant your application will be.

Answer (score 0):

You should give [node.js](https://nodejs.org/) a try.  
Search for "node.js chat apps".
Node.js chat server app is going to have very little memory footprint giving you more memory for the server at runtime.